# PL/SQL null value problem in query

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have to create a pl/sql function which takes seven input parameters.

Problem is user can pass any of these parameters, in any combination such that remaining parameters would be null. Thus a number of combinations is possible.  And I have to query a table using these parameters after removing null parameters.

Is there a way to do this without using number of nested ifs for checking null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also inculde checking the input parameters is null or not in the WHERE clause

For example , suppose the input parameters are parameter1  , parameter2  ,parameter3

```
select * from tableA
where (col1 = parameter1 or parameter1  is null)
and (col2 = parameter2 or parameter2  is null)
and (col3 = parameter3 or parameter3  is null)
```

If the parameter1  is null , it will always return true for this parameter 's conditon.

Answer (score 2):

1 solution is to use logic in your where clause to short circuit the conditions

e.g:

```
SELECT blah WHERE (param1 IS NOT NULL AND col1=param1)
     OR (param2 IS NOT NULL AND col2=param2) ….etc
```

Note: no parameters = no results

or

```
    SELECT blah WHERE (param1 IS NULL OR col1=param1)
     AND (param2 IS NULL OR col2=param2) ….etc
```

Note: no parameters = all results

Comment: +1 that's the way I prefer to do it in this type of situation. Another way would be dynamic sql but I think that's a bit messy and doesn't benefit from compilation checking.

Comment: I agree dynamic sql can also be harder to maintain & debug too.

Comment: this query returns nothing, if one of the parameters is null

Comment: well spotted , have changed the AND to an OR... however the short circuting logic is the important bit

Comment: haha didn't read it properly the correct way is (col=param or param is null) it should be no parameters = all results :) but that might not be what the op wants

Comment: This is still wrong, although differently. Now if I enter both params I would get union of rows returned by each column filter not intersection as is IMO common requirement. Ken Chan's answer is semantically correct, but it would still not use indexes correctly.

Comment: But in this case if first condition is correct second won't be checked. The requirement is if a parameter is not null then it should be checked.

Comment: All 3 methods eliminate the unwanted empty parameters, the ambiguous point is, how it should work, do you want to AND or OR when several parameters are supplied.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
select * from table t where 
(param1 is null or t.column1 = param1) and 
(param2 ....)
```

But this will **NOT** use any indices on the table or, in the worst case, use an inappropriate one (due cursor sharing, can't be avoided before 11G. In 11G it sometimes may work but it is not something you should rely on).

To get a better solution you have to use a dynamic query. In PLSQL this is done using `execute immediate l_query; (or open cursor for l_query;)` for most situations or via more powerfull (but much more complex to use) `DBMS_SQL` (required in very limited number of occurences).

Simpler (but using literals and therefore requiring a hard parse virtually any time it is run) solution is

```
procedure dynamic_query_literals (param1 ... param7)
is
  l_query varchar2(1000);
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
  l_query := 'select * from table t where 1=1';
if (param1 is not null) then 
  l_query := l_query || ' and t.column1 = param1';
end if;
if (param2 ...)
  open l_cursor for l_query;

  -- do whatever needed with the result set in the cursor. 
  --The procedure can even return this cursor...
end;
```

More complex but more performant (particularly if this procedure is called MANY times) solution requires binding of parameters (which gets done automatically and transparently when you use static sql in plsql)

```
procedure dynamic_query_binding (param1 ... param7)
is
  l_query varchar2(1000);
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin
  l_query := 'select * from table t where 1=1';

if (param1 is null) then 
  --this will get optimised away in the process but is required 
  --syntactically for use of "using" later
  l_query := l_query || ' and 1=1 or :param1 is null';
else
  l_query := l_query || ' and t.column1 = :param1';
end if;

if (param2 ...)

open l_cursor for l_query
using param1, param2, ... param7;

  -- do whatever needed with the result set in the cursor. 
  -- The procedure can even return this cursor...
end;
```

This version will use indices on the table as appropriate and still get only one hard parse per unique combination of "nullacy" of parameters.

The downside of both dynamic version is that you don't get compile time syntax checking.

Comment: I have tried both short curcuit methods and both use indexes,

Comment: But you answer different question in your proposed solution. Your answer implies that every parameter is not null. Otherwise it returns nothing. The question IMO demands that null parameter means that resultset should not be filtered by appropriate column.

Comment: Your both answers seem right but for now i am going with first one. I have to check if there are performance related issues. Thanks for help. Just wanted to ask one question is it alright to return refcursor if multiple rows are to be returned.

Comment: Of course, that's what ref_cursors were designed for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
select * from tableA
where col1 = nvl(parameter1, col1) 
and ....
```

Comment: How is this better from the `(col1 = parameter1 or parameter1  is null)` suggested in other answers? I see this form mentioned many times, but what is the advantage? Also, this form does not work correctly if col1 is nullable.